# Search for Dictionary Values in String

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary and I want to see if astring contains any of the keys in the dictionary. If so, I want to replace it with the corresponding value in the dictionary.

```
states = {
     'Alaska' : 'AK',
     'Alabama' : 'AL',}
astring = "I love Alaska"

for state in states:
     if state in astring:
        print astring.replace(state, state.value())
```

This doesn't work of course because in iterating through the keys with the For loop, python is treating state as a string. As a result, there is no value() for state.

Comment: Do you want to replace each word in the same string ? Or make multiple strings where you replace one word from states in each string? For instance if astring='I love Alaska and Alabama', do you want 2 strings: ```'I love AK and Alabama', 'I love Alaska and AL'```, or do you want 1 string: ```'I love AK and AL'```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the key from the `for` loop as the key to your states dict. This should work for you.

```
states = {
     'Alaska' : 'AK',
     'Alabama' : 'AL',}
astring = "I love Alaska"

for state in states:
     if state in astring:
        print astring.replace(state, states[state])
```

It's probably less efficient, but you could also do this

```
states = {
     'Alaska' : 'AK',
     'Alabama' : 'AL',}
astring = "I love Alaska"

for state, abbreviation in states.items():
     if state in astring:
        print astring.replace(state, abbreviation)
```

Comment: @ChrisJ.Vargo No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable `state` is a string, and has no method `.value()`.  I recommend iterating through the entries when you want to use both the key and the value:

```
for state, abbr in states.items():
    if state in astring:
       print astring.replace(state, abbr)
```

Comment: Recommend `states.iteritems()` for Python2.7

Comment: Yes, but then you'll have to update it back to `items()` when the code is updated for Python 3.  :-/  (I recommend using Python 3 for all new/current work!)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case where `astring= 'I love Alaska and Alabama'`. then use

```
new_string = ' '.join([states[word] if word in states else word for word in astring.split()])
#'I love AK and AL'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, slower but shorter:

```
import re

states = {
    'Alaska' : 'AK',
    'Alabama' : 'AL',
}

# build a regexp
pattern = re.compile(
    r'\b(%s)\b' % '|'.join(re.escape(needle) for needle in states)
)

astring = "I love Alaska"

print pattern.sub(lambda match: states.get(match.group()) or match.group(), astring)
```